# Want to simplify $z\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2+z^*\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have an integral that has the term

$z\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2+z^*\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2$

located in an exponent term. I am attempting to solve this integral (there are other terms but I am focused on this one). Clearly, if $z$ was real, this would be pretty simple to simplify; however, $z$ is decidedly complex. I have tried using trigonometric identity $A\cos x+B\sin x=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos[x-\arctan(B/A)]$, but this didn't work. Does anyone have any idea of how to combine these terms somehow? I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: does it help to consider the real and imaginary components of the expression separately?

Comment: @user51547 Not really, my integral is inside an exponent and has other complex functions, I am hoping to express this as some simple Bessel function, so to combine these terms into a single cos, if possible

Answer (score 2):

Using $$\cos(t) = \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}2$$ $$\sin(t) = \frac{e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2i}$$
Then
$$z\cos(A)\cos(B) + w\sin(A)\sin(B)$$
$$\frac z4 \left(e^{i(A+B)} + e^{-i(A+B)} + e^{i(A-B)} + e^{i(B-A)}\right)+ \frac w4 \left(e^{i(A-B)} + e^{-i(B-A)} - e^{i(A+B)} - e^{i(A+B)}\right)$$
$$\frac z2 \left(\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B)\right) + \frac w2 \left(\cos(A - B) - \cos(A + B)\right)$$

Comment: Or, $\Im(z) \cos(A+B) + \Re(z) \cos(A-B)$